# Resolving an ambiguous reference

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a manager class to use with my charting tool, the problem is the tool I use, uses the same names for both a 3d and 2d charts which is resulting in ambiguous reference when I try to add the 2d library.. any ideas how best to resolve this?

For example,

```
using tool.2dChartLib;
using tool.3dChartLib;
```

BorderStyle is a member of both of these

I've tried casting the areas where I use BorderStyle. I suppose it could work if i just reference `tool` but then that would mean I'd have hundreds of `tool.class` lines instead of `class`

Comment: Wait, you can have namespaces that start with digits?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If the types with the same name exist in both namespaces, you have a couple of options:

1) If the number of types is small, create an alias for that type:

```
using BorderStyle3d = tool.3dChartLib.BorderStyle;
```

2) If the number of types is large, you can create an alias for the namespace:

```
using t3d = tool.3dChartLib;
```

Then in your code...

```
t3d.BorderStyle
```

Comment: I ended up using option one.. not ideal but I can see why I have to use it. thanks!

Comment: If you have just a few usages, why not just qualify the type?

Comment: FYI, we dont need to rename the original class name, example: 
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;
using Size = System.Drawing.Size;
using Rect = System.Windows.Rect;

Comment: Nice work. using Object = System.Object; work for me.

Answer (score 11):

You can use full type names, or create aliases:

```
using 2dBorderStyle = tool.2dChartLib.BorderStyle;
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [namespace alias](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011175559/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
using twoDimensionLib = tool.2dChartLib;
using threeDimensionLib tool.3dChartLib;
```

Comment: That would seem to be more verbose (and less readable) than just not including them at all.

Comment: OK. That is truth. But alias longer than namespace :)

Comment: Yes that would. But there is no alternative, if both are required

Comment: @AdamRobinson: **(1)** Keep in mind that "long typing" can be defined by the amount of Intellisense _chunks_ more than character length. `A.B.C.D.Foo` is harder to type than `ABCDEFG.Foo` because `ABCDEFG` can be autocompleted in a single go and `A.B.C.D` cannot (especially if there are many other subnamespaces). **(2)** It's still possible for OP to pick shorter alias names. The names chosen in this answer are a bit long but the point was to showcase the feature rather than suggest the exact names to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem that the class had ambiguous reference for the SAME namespace, so I deleted a specific Project (under Dependencies/{my.prj.name}.API) which had duplicated reference.
After that I referenced Project back with using of CTRL+.
Hope it'll work for you.

[New reference of specific class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TzLY.png)