# Multiple references after upgrading to .net4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have just upgraded my `ASP.NET MVC` web application from `.net4.0` to `.net4.5`, and I am facing several issues where the compiler returns ambiguous references between my (installed as `nuget` package) `entity framework 5.0` libraries and `.net4.5` libraries (basically it doesn't know which one to use).

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework has separate DLLs for each .Net version.

Remove EF entirely, then re-install it from NuGet and everything should work.

Comment: That solved most of the problems. There is one more error - `'CompareAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute' and 'System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute'`. What do I do with that? I already am `using System.Web.Mvc;`.

Comment: @ojek: that is a separate problem for another question, [if it hasn't already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference)