# Never seen a using statement in code used like this

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I find that it helps to download source code to see how things work. I did that with MVCForum, and when viewing the source code noticed a using statement as follows:

```
using MembershipCreateStatus = MVCForum.Domain.DomainModel.MembershipCreateStatus;
```

The MembershipCreateStatus is an enum and is used in different parts of the code as such.

```
if (createStatus != MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
```

Can someone explain why it would be done this way as I have **never seen this before**. Is it easier to do it this way rather than initialize the class?

***************Update***************

Thanks for the answers, sorry it was a duplicate but if I new about alias I would have search for that not "Using Statements"

I understand the use now.

Comment: As you said `MembershipCreateStatus` is a `enum`. Code size is reduced with that alias without reducing readability. What do you mean by "initialize the class"&

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference) was resolved using alias', it shows an example of real world application

Answer (score 1):

It is not a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). It is a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) which is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a shortcut. It defines an "alias" for the long classname. You can use the alias instead of the long name and so it makes your code easier to read. That's all.

Comment: But the alias has exactly the same name as the typename, so they could simply have imported the namespace

Comment: @Dennis_E true, unless another type with exactly the same name exists in an already imported namespace. For example `log4net.ILog` vs `MyProject.ILog`.