# How to deal with different namespaces?

Tags: c#

I have a list of type `A.Composite` and I add a service reference named `ServiceA`. `ServiceA` has a `Composite` class, the same as `A.Composite`.

My issue is that I cannot add the `ServiceA.composite` object to the list because of the difference in the namespace. The first is `A.Composite` and the second `A.ServiceA.Composite`.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Stick to one. Best option would be to only use `A.ServiceA.Composite`.

Comment: Rename the service reference?

Comment: Related: [Resolving an ambiguous reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference)

Comment: "to the list", what list? Are both of the codes referencing the same type, or where do the two types come from? Normally your lists in projects referencing a service would just use the type provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ServiceA has a `Composite` class, the same as `A.Composite`.

If the two classes are the **exact same** (it is just an object returned from the service, picked up in the client in the exact same code), you should include the assembly containing it in your service.

You can read more about it [here](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/08/wcf-tips-and-tricks-share-types-between-server-and-client.html). It explains how to reuse types shared between server and client.

Comment: No, you can't since they aren't considered the same type. You could write an conversion operator though (which I wouldn't advise).

Comment: Is there any way to fix this from the client side without having access to modify the service?

Comment: Yes, the solution referenced would allow you that if you got your service design good. If not, you are stuck with two classes, and all solutions become half working solutions.

Comment: What happens if your client has multiple services? So there is A.Composite B.Composite etc...

Comment: There is still one if they both share the same assembly.

Comment: How do i tell the difference since they share the same names?

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias name as `global::Foo`. So at the top of your source file, just after you using statements, add like this

```
using AliasClass1=global::Foo.Class1;
```

Comment: I don't see how alias will help me in my situation. Could you share more info?