# 2 references have defined the same objects/namespaces

Tags: c#

i'm working on a program at the moment, which uses multiple .dll's as reference. It all worked fine, but yesterday i added a new reference and i got an error on an Object i was using from another reference and it said this object is definded in both .dll Files. I tried removing the other reference but i need what is in that reference so i have to work around it somehow. I searched online but i didn't found a good solution as it seems like not many having this problem! Because of that the help of an experienced programmer is needed more than ever, but i appreciate every piece of help of course :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving an ambiguous reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference)

Answer (score 1):

It's very bad practice to have the same class defined in the same namespace in 2 different assemblies. You have already found out why. This being said, there's a mechanism which allows to disambiguate the references called external aliases.

Let's suppose that you have a console application which references 2 assemblies that contain the same class `Foo.SomeClass` (`ClassLibrary1` and `ClassLibrary2`). In the project where you want to use the class, select the assembly reference and in the Properties window define an alias (in addition to the default `global` alias):

[image]

Do the same for the second assembly reference and use a different alias name.

Now you can use the assembly aliases that you provided to the reference in order to specify the which class you are referring to:

```
extern alias assembly1;
extern alias assembly2;

using FirstClass = assembly1::Foo.SomeClass;
using SecondClass = assembly2::Foo.SomeClass;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c1 = new FirstClass();
            var c2 = new SecondClass();
        }
    }
}
```