# Add image using itextsharp

Tags: image, itext

I am trying to export data in PDF and now i try to add image in PDF using itext sharp i try this but this shows an error ..Is try below code but this shows an error when i add image in PDF file i successfully add text

```
Private Sub ExportGridToPDF()

        Dim headerText As String = "file"


        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        GridView1.AllowPaging = False

        GridView1.DataBind()
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A1, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)

        Dim beginning As New iTextSharp.text.Chunk(headerText)
        Dim p1 As New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(beginning)
        Dim p2 As New iTextSharp.text.Phrase()
        p2.Add(p1)
        Dim p As New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph()
        p.Add(p2)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)

        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(p)

         Dim im As Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/mikesdotnetting.tif")

    pdfDoc.Add(im)


        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```

in this part

```
        Dim im As Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/mikesdotnetting.tif")

    pdfDoc.Add(im)
```

and this shows an error in this line

```
 Dim jpg As Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(New Uri(url))
```

error

```
 **Value of type 'iTextSharp.text.Image' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'.**
```

Any Solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are using two classes named `Image` from a different package / namespace in the same code. That is ambiguous. You should use fully qualified names.

I'm not a .Net developer, but if this were Java, you'd do something like this:

```
Dim im As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/mikesdotnetting.tif")
```

Your problem is caused by the fact that you create a variable `jpg` that is of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`, but you are assigning an object of type `iTextSharp.text.Image` to that variable. It is obvious that this doesn't work.

When you have two classes with the same name (`Image`) in two different namespaces `System.Web.UI.WebControls` and `iTextSharp.text`, you should avoid introducing ambiguities.

Read [Resolving an ambiguous reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference) for more info.

Comment: my bad i removed which i created on top but still shows an error

Comment: this is .net question

Comment: It doesn't matter which language you use. The concept is the same whether you use Java, .NET, or any other technology. Your .NET teacher taught you that there are many classes named `Image` in different .NET libraries. This can lead to ambiguity problems, because a compiler might not know which `Image` class to use. You can introduce disambiguation by using fully qualified names. You *know* this if you paid attention in your programming classes, or if you are self-taught (which is the case for me: I learned from books, not from school).

Comment: Also, you didn't read my answer. The code was C# code, not Java code.