# Unable to get rid of ambiguous path error

Tags: wpf, excel, visual-studio, path, openfiledialog

I've had a look at this post but still can't seem to fix this problem: [Resolving an ambiguous reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference)

I'm trying to make a button in WPF that when clicked browses for an excel file and then opens it. However I keep getting the error

> 'Path' is an ambiguous reference between 'system.windows.shapes.path'
>   and 'system.io.path'

Below is my code. I've tried explicity using

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fileDialog.FileName)
```

Below is my full code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Fasetto
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new WindowViewModel(this);
    }

    private void WindowCloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
    }

    private void WindowMinimizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
    }

    private void WindowMaximizeButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
        fileDialog.ShowDialog();
        string location = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
public class Read_From_Excel
{
    public void getExcelFile(string filename)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);
    }
}
```

This is the line that fires the error, with the variable 'filename' underlined in red:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);
```

Comment: It's still not clear, what and where error at the end you have?

Comment: Hey JohnyL, the error I have is fired from when i try to input the string 'filename' into xlApp.Workbooks.Open. This happens on pretty much my last line of the code block above. The specific error is the ambiguous path error mentioned above.

Comment: And what does error say?

Comment: 'Path' is an ambiguous reference between 'system.windows.shapes.path' and 'system.io.path' - Visual studio underlines the variable 'filename' in red

Comment: Try to remove `using System.IO;`

Comment: Still no good :/

Comment: Perhaps, you're using `Path` somewhere else (I mean - without `System.IO` prefix)

Comment: above is all of the code, i've tried cntrl  + F

Comment: Could you upload your project to some cloud storage for further investigation?

Comment: Sometimes VS is really doing stupid things. Right click on your Project/Solution and Clean. Right click and rebuild... Still doesn't help. Close VS and open again and try CLEAN and REBUILD

Comment: What a waste of 4 hours of my life. I can't believe the turn/off and on again solution worked........

Comment: Thank you very much for your time JohnyL and Nawed for the solution :D