# Always use a defined namespace when ambiguity exists in c#

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

i am writing a programm for a windows form and i use POINT as well as VECTOR.
Point needs using System.Drawing while vector needs System.Windows

If i use both of them i get ambiguity for each created point. I dont want to write everywhere in my code now System.Drawing.Point = new Point

Is there a way to tell the programm to always use the System.Drawing for Points?

I tried adding the WindowsBase.dll but that didnt help. He wouldnt recognise "Vector" as a struct than.

If there is any other way to use Points and Vectors in a WIndows form, that would also be ok. I just dont want to write the namespace each time i use one of those.

Comment: Try adding at top of your file: `using Point = System.Drawing.Point;`

Comment: Put *alias*: `using MyPoint = System.Drawing.Point;` then use `MyPoint`

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference) should solve your problem.

Comment: Wow, using Point = System.Drawing.Point; works! Thank you very much that was easy

Answer (score 1):

Chronicle is right:

```
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;
```