# How to put numbers to pages into PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am new into programming, I tried to make a application with the iTextSharp library which takes a pdf and puts pagenumbers on it and creates a new one.

I tried to make a WinForm application with a example in the internet.

the following code should put pagenumbers to given pdf file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace NummerierePDF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test.pdf");
            Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
                {
                    int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                    {
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetUnderContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
                    }
                }
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Test_1.pdf", bytes);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I get these error messages:

[Erorr messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn8tH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring your local variable `blackFont`, you have to specify the full type name `iTextSharp.text.Font`, because there are different classes that have the name `Font` and the compiler does not know which one to take.

```
iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

See also [Resolving an ambiguous reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference)

Comment: I still get this: Error 1 'System.Drawing.Font' does not contain a definition for 'NORMAL' and no extension method 'NORMAL' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Font' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Z:\programmierung\NummerierePDF\NummerierePDF\Form1.cs 25 84 NummerierePDF

Comment: @TravisTD The same issue. Full type name required. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I changed only 1 line to remove compilation error

change from

```
Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

to

```
iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

it was confusing between System.Drawing.Font and iTextSharp.text.Font because of same namespace. I just added correct namespace

I can see new pdf with page numbers added.

Comment: It works now but on some PDF files it wont show, I think because "stamper.GetUnderConetent(I)" won't work because the whole page is already filled.

Comment: let me check..can you attach one of page where it didnt work..I can then debug

Comment: ah..ok.. I will create such page with pages already filled .. when you meant page is already filled ..does that mean page number was already there or there is no footer to that page ?

Comment: its a scanned paper site. maybe thats the case ?

Comment: ok..I noticed that issue while testing..first I tried scanned page and it didnt work..that was because page was not editable..let me try with scanned page

Comment: Good..Happy to help :)