# Two Grid Packages installed: 'IGrid' is an ambiguous reference between 'GridMvc.IGrid' and 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.IGrid'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-grid

I joined to old MVC project that had a Grid package installed, Grid.MVC. It is used extensively, and taking it out or replacing it is not an option.
We just built out a new portal section to the site, and in it, we used a Telerik.
But here's the problem.

> 'IGrid' is an ambiguous reference between 'GridMvc.IGrid' and 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.IGrid'

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving an ambiguous reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference)

Answer (score 0):

In the your view, enter the fully qualified type name `GridMvc.IGrid` for the model type.

Change value from:
`@model IGrid`
to:
`@model GridMvc.IGrid`